# Setting the default layout

Tags: sublime-text-3

How can I set the default layout in Sublime Text 3's preferences?

I would like the `Columns: 2` layout to be the default whenever I open sublime.

Answer (score 3):

There's no default setting, but a custom plugin will do it.

Go to `Menu > Preferences > Browse Packages...` and the following:

`Packages/User/default_layout.py`.

```
import sublime

def plugin_loaded():
    sublime.active_window().run_command("set_layout", {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
    })
```

Comment: I tried this on SublimeText3, restarted the editor, nothing, still just 1 column :(